# Java Try-with-resource storing input stream in Map

Tags: java, memory-leaks, inputstream, try-with-resources

In my API (Spring boot) I have an endpoint where users can upload multiple file at once. The endpoint takes as input a list of `MultipartFile`.

I wish not to directly pass this `MultipartFile` object to the service directly so I loop through each `MultipartFile` and create a simple map that stored the filename and its `InputStream`.

Like this:

```
for (MultipartFile file : files) {       
      try (InputStream is = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
        filesMap.put(file.getOriginalFilename(), is);
      }
    }
service.uploadFiles(filesMap)
```

My understanding for Java streams and streams closing is quite limited. 
I thought that `try-with-resources` automatically closes the `InputStream` once the code reached the end of the try block.

In the above code when does exactly the the `multipartFile.getInputStream()` gets closed?

The fact that I'm storing the stream in a map will that cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stream closes right after execution reaches closing bracket of `try` block.
It is okay to store `InputStream` anywhere after you closed it.
But be aware of that you **can't read anything** from this stream after you closes it.

*Thanks to comments*

Also, be aware of that some streams have special behavior on `close()` and it always depends on `Stream` realization.
For example:

- If you try to read from closed `FileInputStream` you will get
  `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`
- If you try to read from closed `ByteArrayInputStream` it will be okay, because of it's special `close()` realization: `public void close() throws IOException {}`

Comment: See, that's what I don't understand. the code in the service works perfectly. The input stream is read just fine..

Comment: @Johny19 Its the difference between what you should assume and what is the reality. You should assume that after calling close (or having it called for you) you cannot read anymore from the stream. However, not all InputStream implementations work the same so you may be able to do things that you really shouldn't be doing.

Comment: @Johny19 what is the type of that InputStream? From what you said, I'll bet it's a something like ByteArrayInputStream for example where the close method is empty (no need to close a ByteArrayInputStream directly)

Comment: @Alexis Your comment made me double check and yes you are right! It is indeed a ByteArrayInputStream. This explains why the service is still able to read the stream..

Answer (score 5):

> 1. When does exactly the `multipartFile.getInputStream()` gets closed?

```
try (InputStream is = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
     filesMap.put(file.getOriginalFilename(), is);
} // <-- here
```

> The `try-with-resources` statement ensures that each resource is closed **at the end of the statement**.

---

> 2. The fact that I'm storing the stream in a map will that cause a memory leak?

No, your collection just keeps closed `InputStream`s and you won't be able to read from them (in addition, you will get `IOException`).